# Preventing Navigation Bar for Change Position

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

my app have the ability to support different languages base on what the user choose from the app setting not base on the device language so when my device is english and my app in different language and I open the photo library then closes it the navigation bar for the whole app will change position and I want to know how to prevent this or how to force the photo library to open base on the app language not the device it self so it does not change when I close it??

[image]

```
  let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imagePicker, animated: true)
        present(imagePicker, animated:  true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Are you presenting image picker controller? If yes then don't do in that way. Push imagepicker controller with your root navigation controller.

Comment: I try to do it like this "       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imagePicker, animated: true)" but the app crash

Comment: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: If you show some code on how you are trying to achieve this it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I have edit my question with the code